# 1D string Array comparison with 2D string Array in C

Tags: c, telecommunication

I am working on mobile communication Simulator based on C language. I have two different IPs which are stored as Strings in different format.

1. For User it is XYZ[20]
2. For Access Gateway, it is ABC[No. of Users][20]

Now, I need to compare both for one algorithm. but I am confused that how should I do them as both are different arrays. Is there any way to compare both 1D with 2D array ?

Comment: And I'm confused with your question. Could you be more specific and maybe show some relevant parts of your declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
...
for ( int i = 0; i < num_users; i++ )
{
  if ( strcmp( ABC[i], XYZ ) == 0 )
  {
    // strings are equal
  }
  else
  {
    // strings are not equal
  }
}
```

`ABC[i]` is the `i`'th string stored in `ABC`.

Comment: `strncmp(ABC[i], XYZ, 20)` should be safer.

Comment: Thanks John Bode, It worked for me

Comment: @Jarod: given that the array sizes are the same, the above is only safer if one or the other doesn't have a 0 terminator, meaning there was a coding error somewhere earlier in the code.  I would rather spend those cycles verifying those arrays on assignment than safely comparing invalid data.